# FragmentPagerAdapterのFragmentManagerでの管理

Tags: android, android-fragments

FragmentPagerAdapterをFragment内で使っているのですが、以下のFragmentを表示する時、1回目は表示されるのですが、２回目からFragmentPagerAdapterが？正常に呼び出されず、FragmentAもFragmentBも表示されません。 
FragmentPagerAdapter内はFragmentmanagerにて管理されているため、Fragmentmanagerを更新させる必要があるなどと書かれていたので、それが原因かと素人的に思ったりするのですが、何が原因なのでしょうか？ 
また、解決方法も具体的にご教示頂けますと幸いでございます。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

```
public class Top extends Fragment {

    public static Top newInstance() {
        return new Top();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top, container, false);

        // ViewPagerにMyPagerAdapterを設定
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));

        // PagerSlidingTabStripにViewPagerを設定
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        getActivity().setTitle("テスト");

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final String[] TITLES = {"A", "B"};

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentA();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentB();
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fragment in Fragmentになるので、`getChildFragmentManager()`を渡すのが正しいです。

```
// ViewPagerにMyPagerAdapterを設定
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
```

Comment: なるほど、Fragment in FragmentはgetChildFragmentManegerで渡すのですね。
解決できました。
ありがとうございました。